# Unable to set focus for keyboard input using WindowBuilder SWING UI

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, keyboard-events, windowbuilder

I've written a basic calculator type program using WindowsBuilder in Eclise neon and Java 1.8.  It's pretty much complete, with everything working how I want it to.  Except keyboard entry.

As a finishing touch I'd like to detect keyTyped events and map them to button presses so users can use the keyboard for entry instead of clicking buttons with the mouse.

I've added 'implements KeyListener' to the program class...

```
public class CashRegister implements KeyListener {
    private JTextField keyb;
```

I've tried to set a listener to a invisible JTextField called keyb....

```
private void initialize() {
    keyb = new JTextField(20);
    keyb.addKeyListener(this);
    keyb.setFocusable(true);
    keyb.requestFocusInWindow();
```

And I've added methods to handle the captured keypress...

```
public void keyTyped (KeyEvent e) {
    String out = "";
    out = out + e.getKeyChar();
    pence1text.setText(out);
}
public  void keyPressed (KeyEvent e) {

}
public  void keyReleased (KeyEvent e) {

}
```

So, at this stage all I'm expecting, prove it is working, is the keycharacter I press to appear in the textfield called 'pence1text'.   However, it doesn't work, when I press the a key nothing is displayed.

I think it could be a focus problem.  Googling around and checking stackoverlow lead me to add the following lines...

```
    keyb.setFocusable(true);
    keyb.requestFocusInWindow();
```

as above, but still no luck.

Does anyone have any ideas what I am doing wrong, or what I can try next?

Thanks

Comment: `public boolean requestFocusInWindow()` What is the value of `boolean` returned? Bet it's `false`.

Comment: Yes, it returns false.  I take it thats the problem.  What have I missed?  Thanks.

Comment: Try to read [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) article. Register all your action for your root pane with modifier `JComponent.WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT`.

Comment: *"What have I missed?"* The [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#requestFocusInWindow--), along with the link to *"complete description"* of the method?

Comment: [Listening for Changes on a Document](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#doclisteners) would be a preference to `KeyListener`

Comment: Not sure if you've seen the comment of @MadProgrammer since you entered the answer, but I suspect they've hit the nail on the head. I say 'suspect' only because I saw 'focus' in the title, checked the code and jumped to my conclusions based on this common problem.

Comment: @AndrewThompson, thanks for your help.  Not 100% certain if MadProgrammer's link is what I was looking for.  Maybe it's another/better way of handling what I was trying to do.  However your documentation link sent me in a workable direction.  I moved the KeyListener to another component that's always visable and set it to request focus whenever a user moves it away by pressing a button.  The end app worked how I needed, so all good!  I'll have a deeper look at the other link next time I need to do something similar.

Comment: @BSS-Applications Since we don't actually know what you're trying to do, it's hard to make a suggestion, however, as a general rule, you shouldn't use `KeyListener` with text components, `DocumentListener`, `DocumentFilter` and the key bindings API are all better solutions ... depending on what you're trying to do

Comment: *"As a finishing touch I'd like to detect keyTyped events and map them to button presses so users can use the keyboard for entry instead of clicking buttons with the mouse"* - Ok, but what's the got to with the textfield?  Buttons already support short cut keys (mnemonics)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to user Andrew Thompson for pointing me back to the docs and a re-read.

The problem is that the JTextField is not visable and thus can't be given focus.  If I add the listener to a textfield that is visable then the program works correctly.   However if the user uses the mouse to click a button it loses focus and breaks the implementation...so I need to rethink the code and keep looking at focuse settings.

Answer (score 1):

> As a finishing touch I'd like to detect keyTyped events and map them to button presses so users can use the keyboard for entry instead of clicking buttons with the mouse.

Don't use a KeyListener.

Instead you should be using `Key Bindings`. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) for basic information.

Also check out: [how to put actionlistenerand actioncommand to multiple jbuttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35906270/how-to-put-actionlistenerand-actioncommand-to-multiple-jbuttons/35906545#35906545) for a working example that shows how you can apply the key bindings to a calculator.