# Attaching multiple keybindings to a java swing object

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, key-bindings

I have an issue where I am trying to make "player" icon move around my JFrame using keyboard controls. I have one object that I want to move around with the w, a, s, and d keys. I am using key bindings because in my research it seems that they are better suited to this task.

I have managed to attach all the desired keys to my icon, and they all call the action, the only issue is that I have no way to distinguish which button is being pressed. I was hoping this could be accomplished in some way by using the `getActionCommand()` on my action event. So far it hasn't worked.

Other examples that I have seen seem to have a solution to this, but they also have a lot of extra code with few comments, making it extremely difficult to determine what is actually happening. They all seem to involve multiple classes, with methods and fields. I am hoping to make this code a little less involved.

What I want to know: What is the best way to get this to work? Can I do it with key bindings? Does it need to be really complicated?

I really appreciate any help, even if it's just sources that I can use to help find an answer on my own.

Here's my existing code:

```
//My method that gets called by the constructor
//This is all based on a tutorial I found: ftp://ecs.csus.edu/clevengr/133/handouts/UsingJavaKeyBindings.pdf
//player is just an image icon
public static void setUpKeys() {
    InputMap playerMap = player.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);

    KeyStroke wKey = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke('w');
    KeyStroke aKey = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke('a');
    KeyStroke sKey = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke('s');
    KeyStroke dKey = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke('d');
    KeyStroke wSprint = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke((char) ('w' + KeyEvent.SHIFT_DOWN_MASK)); //As a side note, what's the best way to get it to move faster when the shift key is held down? Not that important, but if someone happens to know, that'd be great

    playerMap.put(wKey, "moveUp");
    playerMap.put(aKey, "moveLeft");
    playerMap.put(sKey, "moveDown");
    playerMap.put(dKey, "moveRight");
    playerMap.put(wSprint, "moveFast");

    ActionMap playerAction = player.getActionMap();

    playerAction.put("moveUp", playerMoved);
    playerAction.put("moveLeft", playerMoved);
    playerAction.put("moveDown", playerMoved);
    playerAction.put("moveRight", playerMoved);
    playerAction.put("moveFast", playerMoved);
}
```

And here is my playerMoved action:

```
static Action playerMoved = new AbstractAction() {
    //This isn't important, just put it in instead of suppressing the warning
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2L; 

    //This doesn't do anything yet, just gives console confirmation
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Activated");

        //Here's what I was talking about with the getActionCommand() not working
        if (e.getActionCommand().equals("moveUp")) {
            System.out.println("up");
        }
    }
};
```

If anyone needs any other parts of my code, I can provide it. I just wanted to cut it down to what I feel is important for this question

Comment: As author of several of the answers that you might be referring to, I have to ask you to try to improve your question -- please be more specific about just what code you refer to, what's confusing about it, what you're trying to achieve with your own code... You're likely going to need an animation loop of some sort -- how do you plan to implement this? Also, most of the answers posted show a valid [mcve] -- compilable runnable code, something that you're question is lacking.

Comment: Your `playerMoved` `Action` should have some kind of identifier/delta applied to it, so that when it's called, it knows what it has to do - basically using the same instance of `Action` is a bad idea

Comment: `They all seem to involve multiple classes, with methods and fields.` - not that I have seen. They usually involve a basic `Action` class that takes parameters so you can easily define movement without hardcoding. They also usually define a method for assigning the key bindings to a KeyStroke and an Action, again to simplify code so you don't keep repeating the same code multiple time. `I have no way to distinguish which button is being pressed` - that is why you pass parameters to an Object when you create it.

Comment: For example check out the `MotionWithKeyBindings` code found in [Motion Using the Keyboard](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/06/09/motion-using-the-keyboard/). If there is something you don't understand then ask a specific question. We can't guess what you find confusing about a reusable class and a convenience method. Note: once you understand this basic example you may want to move on to the `KeyboardAnimation` examples which adds more features to handle multiple keys pressed at the same time.

Comment: @VasylLyashkevych, that example does nothing to show how to use an parameterized Action so that you can use the same Action to move up/down/left/right just by changing the parameters. The OPs question is about determining what key is pressed when the same Action is used.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. It seems that the best decision is to continue researching this topic and when I run into further issues, ask a more detailed and answerable question, which this is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I was hoping this could be accomplished in some way by using the getActionCommand() on my action event.

You don't want to do this because you would be attempting to use the "action command" for "processing". That is not a good design as it will result in nested if/else statements.

Instead you need to create an `Action` that accepts parameters to control the movement. So you will need 4 separate Actions to control the movement. See the `MotionWithKeyBindings` example found in [Motion Using the Keyboard](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/06/09/motion-using-the-keyboard/), for a complete working example of this approach.

It demonstrates how a simple `Action` can be made reusable by specifying parameters for the `Action`. This provides far more flexibility than your current Action.

**Note 1:**

You use the following debug code in your `Action`:

```
System.out.println("Activated");
```

Instead of simply displaying a hard coded value it would be better to do something like

```
System.out.println( e.getActionCommand() );
```

In which case you should notice the value is "a, s, w, d", which is the `KeyStroke` you use to invoke the `Action`.

So this would mean the if statement should be testing for either of the above characters, not the String "moveUp" which is the String used to identify the `Action` in the `ActionMap`.

However, as mentioned above, this is not the solution you should be using, I just wanted to better explain how the "action command" is determined.

**Note 2:**

The only time you might want to use a single `Action` and the `getActionCommand()` method is when you want to use the "action command" as "data" for the `Action`.

For an example of this approach check out: [how to put actionlistenerand actioncommand to multiple jbuttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35906270/how-to-put-actionlistenerand-actioncommand-to-multiple-jbuttons/35906545#35906545). It is an example of a simple numeric entry panel where the number key pressed is added to a text field. So therefore the key character becomes the data for the text field and no special processing is required.

Comment: Thank you for your contribution. I realize that my question not phrased in the best manner, and as such may have been unnecessarily difficult to answer. I appreciate pointing out that I could have just printed out the getActionCommand, because that didn't even occur to me. I'll consider what you've said, and find my own way around this problem.