# How to Assign different keys to SWING Action?

Tags: java, swing, awt

I'm going to reimplement numpad (Somewhat similar to calculator pane) inside a SWING application. It must respond on both numkeys (numlock section) and numeric keys (right below function keys). The current solution captures the input for the whole frame and requests focus after each action. I found this solution clumsy and want to use the SWING `Action`s. But, it's quite tricky to make it work for both different keys.
 - Could it be done?
 - How to make in the most elegant and performance effective way?

Comment: [Key Bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html)

Comment: See the `Calculator Panel` example in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35906270/how-to-put-actionlistenerand-actioncommand-to-multiple-jbuttons/35906545#35906545 for a working example that uses Key Bindings to bind both keys to the same Action.