# How could I generate functional buttons from a list of objects using a for loop?

Tags: java, eclipse, swing

I'm using java swing, and I can already generate objects with a for loop just fine. Where I'm getting stuck, is making generated buttons functional.

This is the method I normally use to tell what button was clicked.
But this requires each button to first be defined outside the constructor.

```
Button_1 = new JButton("OK");
    Button_1.setBounds(20, 60, 340, 20);
    Button_1.addActionListener(this);
    panel.add(Button_1);
}


@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
        
    if (e.getSource() == button_1) {
        System.out.println("Button 1 was clicked");
        
    }
    if (e.getSource() == button_2) {
        System.out.println("Button 2 was clicked");
        
    }
}
```

How do I define a button within a for loop, and have it be detectable?

Comment: Don't use setBounds(). Swing was designed to be used with layout managers.

Answer (score -1):

Nevermind, figured it out. If anyone else is trying to figure this out, here's the answer.

```
for (String listedString : list) {
Button = new JButton("OK");
    Button.setBounds(20, 60, 340, 20);
    Button.addActionListener(e -> PressedButton(listedString));
    panel.add(Button_1);
}


private Object PressedButton(String listedString) {
        System.out.println(listedString);
        return null;
```

Comment: Follow the naming conventions. `PressedButton` should be `pressedButton`, among others. Only use capitalization for type names, not variables, not methods.

Comment: Don't use a for loop. Buttons , like "OK" and "Cancel" should have its own custom ActionListener. You should NOT be using if statements inside the ActionListener  to text which button was clicked. However, if you have generic functionality for each button then you can create a generic listener and use the `getSource(...)` method of the ActionEvent to access the button that was clicked. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35906545/131872 for an example of this approach.

Comment: Letting aside the ignorance towards naming conventions, the variable should have at least the same name at all places where it is used. And you’re creating an arbitrary number of buttons with the same label but different behavior.